# Bootstrap Hugo Docs Site will not build "render of 'page' failed"

Tags: html, macos, terminal, bootstrap-5, hugo

I have the [source code of bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/) downloaded on my mac with all of the nescessary node packages installed. I tried running `hugo --cleanDestinationDir --printUnusedTemplates` (hugo is installed) and I got this error:

```
ERROR 2023/06/20 11:07:41 render of "page" failed: "/Users/admin/Documents/GitHub/bootstrap_playground/site/layouts/_default/baseof.html:4:7": execute of template failed: template: _default/docs.html:4:7: executing "_default/docs.html" at <partial "header" .>: error calling partial: partial "header" timed out after 30s. This is most likely due to infinite recursion. If this is just a slow template, you can try to increase the 'timeout' config setting.
ERROR 2023/06/20 11:07:41 render of "page" failed: "/Users/admin/Documents/GitHub/bootstrap_playground/site/layouts/_default/baseof.html:4:7": execute of template failed: template: _default/docs.html:4:7: executing "_default/docs.html" at <partial "header" .>: error calling partial: partial "header" timed out after 30s. This is most likely due to infinite recursion. If this is just a slow template, you can try to increase the 'timeout' config setting.
ERROR 2023/06/20 11:07:41 render of "page" failed: "/Users/admin/Documents/GitHub/bootstrap_playground/site/layouts/_default/baseof.html:4:7": execute of template failed: template: _default/docs.html:4:7: executing "_default/docs.html" at <partial "header" .>: error calling partial: partial "header" timed out after 30s. This is most likely due to infinite recursion. If this is just a slow template, you can try to increase the 'timeout' config setting.
ERROR 2023/06/20 11:07:41 render of "page" failed: "/Users/admin/Documents/GitHub/bootstrap_playground/site/layouts/_default/baseof.html:4:7": execute of template failed: template: _default/docs.html:4:7: executing "_default/docs.html" at <partial "header" .>: error calling partial: partial "header" timed out after 30s. This is most likely due to infinite recursion. If this is just a slow template, you can try to increase the 'timeout' config setting.
Total in 119825 ms
Error: error building site: render: failed to render pages: render of "page" failed: "/Users/admin/Documents/GitHub/bootstrap_playground/site/layouts/_default/baseof.html:4:7": execute of template failed: template: _default/404.html:4:7: executing "_default/404.html" at <partial "header" .>: error calling partial: partial "header" timed out after 30s. This is most likely due to infinite recursion. If this is just a slow template, you can try to increase the 'timeout' config setting.
```

I did the same thing in replit and it worked fine. I am on macOS 13 with npm 9.7.1 and node 18.16.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to install or create a Hugo site **with a theme that uses bootstrap**. You can not install Hugo and Bootstrap, and expect both to work together out of the box.

Follow the [Hugo Quick start section](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/quick-start/) to create a Hugo site, then add Bootstrap to the theme or to the baseof.html template to be able to use it.

Comment: @PeterSmith If you look at the bootstrap source code on github, you can see that there is the site files that can be built into the bootstrap docs. Infact, this is how bootstrap hosts there docs. As stated in the question, this process has worked on another machine.